# Im getting Type error code valid intents must be provided for the Client when coding a crypto bot from a tutorial

Tags: discord

**This is my bot.js file**

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js');

const dotenv = require('dotenv');

// Load environment variables
dotenv.config();

// Create a bot instance
const bot = new Client();

// Log our bot in
bot.login(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);
```

**This is my .env file**

```
DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN = my discord bot token
```

**This is my .gitignore file**

```
node_modules/

.env
```

**This is the error code**

```
C:\Users\aslat\OneDrive\Desktop\ScrtBot\crypto-discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:548
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\aslat\OneDrive\Desktop\ScrtBot\crypto-discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:548:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aslat\OneDrive\Desktop\ScrtBot\crypto-discord-bot\bot.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
}
```

Comment: You need to generate a new Discord Token, do not post those for anyone to see as they can use it to log in as your bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your bot.js file

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');

const dotenv = require('dotenv');

// Load environment variables 

dotenv.config();

// Create a bot instance 

const bot = new Client({
    // the below line is what you were missing. 
    intents: 32767 // you can change this if you want but that number is the code for all intents
    });

// view intents here https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents
// Log our bot in

bot.login(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);
```

Also as mentioned before, get a new discord token as posting it here has compromised the security of your bot.

Answer (score -1):

Please try again using the structured file in the current working directory. e.g.:

```
// Importing a local module with a path relative to the `__dirname` or current
// working directory. (On Windows, this would resolve to .\path\myLocalModule.)
const myLocalModule = require('./path/myLocalModule');
```